# Implementing an Account class

Tags: java

I have a java file with a Class named Client which i will use to store client registry information, their name and email, that will be their account login info. And I'm a bit stuck here.

This is a bit of code of what i have so far

```
public class ClientAccount {

  private String name;
  private String email;
 /**This intializes an instance of ClientAccount
  public ClientAccount(String name, String email) {

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
```

This is the class that will return a string with the Client name and email.

Now I need a method that creates and instance of client from a string.

```
    /**
 * Creates an instance of Client from a String.
 * 
 * @param s a String
 * @return an instance of Client
 * @requires s is a string that contains the email address of the client 
 * and its name, separated by a comma (,). The string must contain exactly 
 * one comma.
 * @ensures the returned value c is such that c.getEmail is equal to the 
 * email address specified in s and c.name is equal to the name specified 
 * in s.
 */
public static ClientAccount fromString(String s) {

}
```

s is a string that contains the email address of the client 
      and its name, separated by a comma. Return an instance of Client

```
public String toString() {
    // TODO
    return this.email+","+this.name;
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: "I have a java file with a Class named Client" I see a class named `ClientAccount`, not `Client`. I suggest you learn to be this nitpicky about details because computers are relentlessly literal when you try to program them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice true that's because i change some code meanwhile, before i posted the question mb.

Comment: For future reference, you should avoid these types of inconsistencies when asking questions. They often result in wasted time asking for and providing clarifications which delays someone being able to answer your question. If you are more precise in your question to start with, you can get your answer sooner and move on to the next part of what you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the input string to get the separate name and email. If the input is in the same format as you return from `toString()`, then you can use `String.split()`. I suggest you use Google to find the documentation for the String class and read about this method. One thing to be careful about is that there are no commas in the email or name. This shouldn't be an issue with an email, but could be for a name depending on how it is entered.

Comment: I just not sure if my toString method is even done rigth.

Comment: @Exzlanttt Your question does not provide enough information for me to judge if it is right, either.

Comment: i can post the javadoc for the fromString method

Comment: @Exzlanttt Feel free to edit your question with these details. You should also ask an explicit question about what you do not understand how to do.

Comment: @Exzlanttt After looking at the javadoc in your edit, my answer appears to be exactly what you need to do.

Comment: yea im using this ---> String[] clients = s.split(",");

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) `split` method and get the elements (email and name) as shown below:

```
public static ClientAccount fromString(String s) {
   //split the string using ,
   String[] elements = s.split(",");

   //elements[1] is name
   //elements[0] is email
   ClientAccount clientAccount = new ClientAccount(elements[1], elements[0]);

   return clientAccount;
}
```

**ClientAccount Class with getters and setters:**

```
public class ClientAccount {

          private String name;
          private String email;

          public ClientAccount(String name, String email) {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i want to have a public string getEmail() { , what would it be the return value? something like ->  return clientAccount.email?

Comment: Yes, you need getters and setters, Refer above class

Comment: @Exzlanttt I suggest you learn about the difference between accessing elements with an reference variable and elements of the current object.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could also overload the constructor in your class as:

```
public ClientAccount(String s) {
   String[] elements = s.split(",");

   this.name = elements[1];
   this.email = elements[2];
}
```

...and then do elsewhere: `ClientAccount clientAccount = new ClientAccount(s);`

Note that this simple version assumes that you have a nice looking input string. In a real application you probably want to do some regexp pattern matching before the split in order to check whether the string is of the correct form (email+comma+name).